# 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable when working with matrices

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, matrix, rotation

I have a datafarame s9 with three columns x,y,x.
I want to multiply each row as a matrix with a 3*3 matrix `R910` and get an array `s910`.
This is the code I have written but I get the error:

```
'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable`
```

After I get the resulting matrix, I would like to add a 1*3 matrix to the result.

```py
for i in range(len(s9.values)):
    np.matmul(R910*s9.values(i))
return s910
```

Comment: Please provide more information of what you have tried and what your code looks like. From the snippet it's not clear how s9 or R910 is defined.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not solve your issue, as you didnt give enough information, but from what i can see your using the function matmul wrong. If you are using the function np.matmul, it is doing the multiplication for you.
So instead of `matmul(array1*array2)` you should write `matmul(arra1,array2)`